# Using a SQL table to handle state transitions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Order (MVC) system where the orders transition to different states, i.e new order, paid, shipped, etc.  Each state can have multiple transitions.  Originally I thought I would have a status table with an ID and Description and then a transition table that would have current status and transitions status, with each transition on a single row.  In order to populate a selection box, I would have to do the join to get the descriptions.  Now I am thinking I could do it all in one table and add a comma separate column which would list the possible transitions.  Is this a good idea or is there a better way?

Comment: i am sorry but I didn't understand the difference between Order Status and transitions status. can you give some example with data to understand it.

Comment: This question may be primarily opinion based and not suitable for SO. I prefer a join over comma separated column. Makes querying things much easier later on, for ad hoc queries for example. Plus you join on ID's and if you want to change the label at some point you don't have a massive replace. With proper indexes in place, searching / querying by status will also perform better when using a lookup table. Also, I hate commas. I always have, and I always will. I will never forgive them for taking my bacon.

Comment: @AnupShah, order status is the current status and transition status is where it can go next.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin, I understand about a question based on opinion, but what I am after is how others have solved this issue.  I started down the road of a lookup table, but was thinking there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any RDBMS promotes database normalization, There are 6 forms of database normalization. Normally if you can get to first three it is good enough.

**The first Normal Form states**: you should have only one piece of information in a column and a column should store on one piece/Type of information.

Now if your case when you are try to save a comma deliminited list of transitions. if you have to pick only record with a particular type of transitions state?? it will be a messy query.

Also imagine a scenario where you have to update a column for a particular record when transition state is changed, again a very messy , error prone and performance killer query.

Therefore follow the basic rules of Database Normalization, and stick to your 1st which was to create a separate table and use IDs to define transition state, and add a new row whenever a transition changes.

*My Suggestion*

Simply Have one column for [current status] and one Column for [transition], add a new row everytime any of the values change.

Also a datetime column with default value to current datetime. Which will allow you to go back in history and see different status and transition states of a record in point in time.

Have only one column in only One table which stores this information reference this column in other tables if you need to.